# insert into mysql table on a remote server where data is coming from a file

Tags: mysql, insert

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL table. The table has just two columns: id and name. 
My text file has all the names I want to load in it, separated by newlines. The MySQL table is based in the Amazon cloud.

Is there a easier way to load data into the table than writing insert statements for each of the lines?

Answer (score 0):

Try MySQL [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE users.txt INTO TABLE users LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Does LOAD Data infile work with remote server. My text file is on my computer and mysql is running on amazon s3. ??

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Get an application like HeidiSQL that can do this for you.
2. My favorite kludge is to write a bash script to translate the input into a series of INSERT statements, then run that with the mysql CLI.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you have a text file, simple as that I'll would use simple approach. I read that file with StreamReader:

```
string row = null;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    while ((row = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] words = row.Split(' ');

                        foreach (string word in words)
                        {
                        //do what ever you want
                        //you have word[0] as ID and word[1] as name                              
                        }
                    }
                }
```